# Java - having trouble with capturing data from text file

Tags: java, bufferedreader, printwriter

um.. I try my best to explain however I can.. well.. I've this text/dat file with data inside. When I run the code, this error message "Error! Incorrect username or password!" although username and password is already in the file. Below are the code, output and the file.

here's the code of GameModule.java:

```
public void run()
    {
        System.out.println("FISHING PAIR GAME LOGIN");
        Utility.printLine(50);
    System.out.println();

        ArrayList<Player> players = new ArrayList<>();
        Scanner myScanner=null;
        try {
            myScanner = new Scanner (new File("players.dat"));
            while (myScanner.hasNextLine())
            {

                String data = myScanner.nextLine();

                String [] dataSplit = data.split("\\|");
                Player existingPlayer = new Player (dataSplit[0], dataSplit[1],dataSplit[2], Integer.parseInt(dataSplit[3]));
                players.add(existingPlayer);
            }


        }   catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {

            System.out.println("Error! File - players.dat not found!");
        }

        myScanner.close();
        //End of read file into array

        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        boolean exist = false;

        System.out.print("Enter Login name > ");
        String userName = input.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Enter Password > ");
        String userPW = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println();
        for (int i=0; i < players.size(); i++) {
            //Verifies user login name and password
            if (players.get(i).getLoginName().equalsIgnoreCase(userName)&&(players.get(i).checkPassword(userPW)))
            {
                char continueGame='y';
                //Loop for allowing player to continue the game
                while(continueGame=='y'||continueGame=='Y') {
                    //Ensure player have sufficient chips to play the game
                    if (players.get(i).getScores()>0) {
                        //Game function which returns the chips of the player after the game
                        players.get(i).setScores(startGame(players.get(i).getLoginName(), players.get(i).getScores()));
                        System.out.print("Next Game? (Y/N) > ");
                        continueGame = input.next().charAt(0);
                    } else {
                        continueGame = 'n';
                        System.out.println("Sorry you do not have enough chips.");
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("Thank you for playing, see you again!");
                exist = true;
            }       
         }
        //If user id or password does not match or incorrect
         if (exist == false) {
            System.out.println("Error! incorrect username or password!");
         }

       //Write array into file
         try {
            PrintWriter fileOut = new PrintWriter("players.dat");
            //BufferedWriter fileOut = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("players.dat", false));
            for (int i = 0; i < players.size(); i++) {
             fileOut.println(players.get(i).getLoginName() + "|" + players.get(i).getHashPass() + "|" + players.get(i).getDate() + "|" 
                                + players.get(i).getScores());
             //fileOut.printLn();
            }
             fileOut.close();
             //System.out.println("Data saved");

         } catch (IOException e) {
             System.out.println("Failed to open file");   
         }
    }
```

`Player` is another java file/class. `startGame()` is a method in the GameModule.

As you can see the code that..it first checks if players.dat exist or not. then goes to the login part. during login, it will check if the username and/or password is in the file or not.

this is the output:

```
FISHING PAIR GAME LOGIN
--------------------------------------------------
Enter Login name> IcePeak
Enter Password> p1

Error! incorrect username or password!
```

in the players.dat file--

IcePeak|p1|-|10

BlueKnight|p2|-|10

BlackRanger|p3|-|10

GoldDigger|p4|-|10

The '-' is to indicate the login date. since the players are new, there is no date.

well, you can see that IcePeak and the password p1 is already stored in that file but I got that error message. I've re-read all the codes line by line and I even re-typed. I forgot another thing I've tried. I even deleted the file and re-created it with the same info.But I'm still getting the same error message.I just don't know and don't understand what went wrong :(

so please help me out, thanks :)

**EDIT - added Player.java**

```
/**
 * CSCI213 Assignment 1
 * ------------------
 * File name: Player.java
 * Author: Kanak Priya Selvarani
 * UOW Student number: 4641619
 * Description: Player class. This class contains player's details which will be saved in players.dat file.
 */
//package assignment1_kanakpriyaselvarani;
package admin;
import admin.User;
import java.util.ArrayList;
//import User.java;

/**
 *
 * @author SONY
 */
public class Player extends User{
    private int scores;
    private String date;
    //private String loginName, hashedPassword;
    ArrayList<Card>cardsOnHand;

    public Player(String loginName, String hashPass, String date, int scores)
    {
        super(loginName,hashPass);
        //this.loginName = loginName;
        //this.hashedPassword = hashedPassword;
        this.scores = scores;
        this.date = date;
        cardsOnHand = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public String getDate()
    {
        return date;
    }

    public int getScores()
    {
        return scores;
    }

    public void addScores(int scores)
    {
        this.scores+=scores;
    }

    public void deductScores(int scores)
    {
        this.scores-=scores;
    }

    public void setScores(int scores)
    {
        this.scores=scores;
    }

    public int  getNumOfCards()
    {
        return cardsOnHand.size();
    }

    public void addCard(Card card)
    {
        cardsOnHand.add(card);
    }

    public void showCards()
    {
        System.out.println(getLoginName());
        for(Card c:cardsOnHand)
        {
            System.out.print(c+ " ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }

    public void showCardsValue()
    {
        System.out.println("Value:"+getTotalCardsValue());
    }

    public int getTotalCardsValue()
    {
        int totalValue=0;

        for(Card c:cardsOnHand)
        {  
            totalValue+=c.getValue();
        }

        return totalValue;        
    }

    //Thinks of the action that a player can take, implements those action as methods...



    public static void main(String []args)
    {
        //testing of getTotalCardsValue()    
        Player p = new Player("tester","","",0);

        Card c1 = new Card("Heart","Ace",1);
        Card c2 = new Card("Heart","Queen",10);

        p.addCard(c1);
        p.addCard(c2);

        p.showCards();
        p.showCardsValue();

        Card c3 = new Card("Heart","3",3);
        p.addCard(c3);
        p.showCards();
        p.showCardsValue();


    }
}
```

**SECOND EDIT - User.java**

```
/*
 * CSCI213 Assignment 1
 * -----------------
 * File name: User.java
 * Author: Kanak Priya Selvarani
 * UOW Student Number: 4641619
 * Description: User Class. This is for login name and password of admin and player.
 *
 */
//package assignment1_kanakpriyaselvarani;
//import Utility.java;
package admin;
abstract public class User {

    private String loginName;
    private String hashPass;
    private String date;
    private int scores;

    public User(String loginName,String hashPass)
    {
        this.loginName = loginName;
        this.hashPass = hashPass;
    }


    public String getLoginName()
    {
        return loginName;
    }

    public String getHashPass()
    {
        return hashPass;
    }

    public void setHashPass(String newHashPass)
    {
        this.hashPass = newHashPass;
    }

    public boolean checkPassword(String password)
    {
        boolean status = false;
        String hash = Utility.getHashPass(password);

        if(hashPass.equals(hash))
        {
            status = true;
        }

        return status;
    }

}
```

Comment: try with putting `players.get(i).getLoginName()` in System.out.println() just inside you for loop and check what is value it prints, i doubt `players` is empty or `loginName` or `password` is not setting correctly in players.

Comment: Learn to use a debugger, execute the program line by line, and inspect the values in your variables. That will take less time than writing this question, and will save you days and days.

Comment: @hello show your Player class

Comment: @RobertoDeLaParra I added in the Player.java

Comment: @MitulSanghani i'll try that

Comment: @hello I don't see this method checkPassword in player.java where is it?

Comment: I don't see the function players.get(i).checkPassword(userPW), ? I'd bet the problem is inside of it

Comment: @RobertoDeLaParra checkPassword() method is inside another class User.java. I forgot about it. i'm now gonna post its code

Comment: print the content of this both vars before the if  `if(hashPass.equals(hash))`. is the pwd in the file hashed or is it plain text?

Comment: @RobertoDeLaParra the pwd is plain text.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out what's the problem

Inside my players.dat file, it should be hashed password instead of normal password.

Since my files are linked together (polymorphism), and all the files share the players.dat file. Plus, the files have the codes for hashed password.

Thanks helping me out btw ^^

Answer (score -1):

My suspicion is that your input may contain non-displayable characters. Your using String.equalsIgnoreCase() that should work however if the input contained "space or control" characters, Java won't match it completely. Try trim() it first. You should be able to print out both username and password into the console with quotes around it just to double check.

I know this is not the answer but I have not got enough reputation to add comments :(